# Search for specific name across (some) tags and convert to link

Tags: javascript, html

I am writing some javascript for my website.

I would like to be able to turn (using javascript) specific names into links.

for example, given the name Benjamin it would turn :

```
Hello my name is Benjamin
```

into

```
Hello my name is <a href='something'>Benjamin</a>
```

The trick is, I don't know what names I need to convert in advance, I receive those in an ajax response. Also, I need to be able to handle stuff along the lines of

```
<b>B</b>enjam<b>in</b>
```

while not touching stuff like

```
B<br />enja<br />min
```

I would like to know what would be the best practice for designing something able to do this sort of parsing. If there is a ready solution that would probably be better.

Thanks in advance for the help

Comment: I'll sit here and wait for you to finish the question.

Comment: Thanks :S I didn't notice it posted, new keyboard ^_^

Comment: It's quite straightforward to search and replace strings of text. Your problem is that you need to be able to detect words split across tags. Can you elaborate on why you need that?

Comment: jQuery won't be of great help in here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apply this to your text:

```
.replace(new RegExp("Benjamin".split('').join(".*?"),"g"),'<a href="#">$&</a>')
                  //    ^------------------------ word to be replaced
```

[Live demo](http://jsfiddle.net/9MEfS/)

Comment: Nice use of a reluctant quantifier but this does not solve my problem. It would also match "ben likes some jammin" and stuff like that.

Comment: @BenjaminGruenbaum You can improve '`.`' sign replacing it by allowed symbols and/or sequences of symbols.E.g. `[^\s]` or `<br\s?/?>` or etc..

Comment: Yes, I just figured it out replacing the .* with <.*>*? , thanks!

Answer (score 0):

This Regex matches all those Names, 
this way:

```
var str1 = "Hello Im Benjamin";
var str2 = "Hello Im <b>Benjamin</b>";
var str3 = "Hello Im <b>Benj<b>amin</b></b>"
var str4 = "Hello Im <br>Benjamin< />"    

console.log(str1.match(/ (?:(?:<b>)?[^><\s]?(?:<\/b>)?)*$/)); //[" Benjamin"] 
console.log(str2.match(/ (?:(?:<b>)?[^><\s]?(?:<\/b>)?)*$/)); //[" <b>Benjamin</b>"] 
console.log(str3.match(/ (?:(?:<b>)?[^><\s]?(?:<\/b>)?)*$/)); //[" <b>Benj<b>amin</b></b>"] 
console.log(str4.match(/ (?:(?:<b>)?[^><\s]?(?:<\/b>)?)*$/)); //null
​
```

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/EcLkp/)

Comment: Interesting, but seems to match only the last word not "Benjamin"